# Como trabalhar com OCR para reconhecer fotografias

Tags: c#, java, c, python, ocr

Atualmente estou trabalhando em meu Trabalho de Conclusão de Curso e o tema envolve OCR.
Fiz algumas pesquisas e encontrei o [Tesseract](https://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/), também encontrei bibliotecas no Nuget pra ele (estou usando C#). O problema é que meu trabalho é sobre leitura de Placa Veicular, quando passo uma imagem de um carro (daquelas que os radares tiram), o tesseract não consegue fazer a leitura da imagem, diz que a imagem é inválida. Tentei com várias imagens diferentes, com imagens que só tinha a placa e sempre a mesma coisa *(entenda coisa como erro)*. Porém se eu criar uma imagem no Paint com um texto e tentar ler, funciona, **mas não é isso que quero**.

Gostaria de saber se alguém já teve experiência com isso e sabe como resolver, ou se conhece outra forma de trabalhar com OCR e que atenda esta necessidade.

Se conhecer outra forma de *fazer em outra linguagem*, por favor me diga, posso desenvolver em outra linguagem que não seja C#.

Comment: Em que formato você está passando a imagem para o Tesseract?

Comment: Tentei com Tif, Jpg e Bmp.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A solução completa pode ser vista [neste video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RqvvXJXuRYY). Para o que eu preciso é necessário utilizar EmguCV, OpenCV e tesseract.
Assim consigo fazer a leitura de placas veiculares.

Answer (score 6):

Tem um cara chamado OpenCV que resolve seus problemas, ele consegue capturar não só de Imagem como de vídeo também, inclusive estou tendo que estudar ele que possui implementação em C, C++, Java e Python (optei por python).

http://opencv.org/new-opencv-books.html

Estou pensando seriamente em comprar este livro inclusive, pois, tenho muito interesse e necessidades no tema.

[Link OpenCV](http://opencv.org/)

Comment: será que ele lê a placa do jeito que preciso? Sabe se tem algum demo que eu consiga fazer este teste?

Answer (score 3):

Tive o mesmo problema alguns dias atras. Depois de testar algumas a que melhor funcionou para o meu caso foi o [ocrad](http://antimatter15.com/ocrad.js/demo.html), que é em javascript. Eu precisava reconhecer o título da imagem de uma foto tirada de um documento.

O bom que ele te da a pontuação de reconhecimento. No meu caso quando ele dava uma pontuação maior que 60%, considerava como reconhecido. Mas pra mim só funcionou bem depois de editar a imagem, recortando somente a parte que ele precisava reconhecer.

No seu caso seria interessante ele avaliar somente a parte dos caracteres da placa, acho que teria resultados melhores.

Comment: Vi o demo dele, achei muito fraco para o que eu preciso. Mas obrigado por responder!

Comment: Pois é, no seu caso acho que tem que ser algo mais robusto. Boa sorte, se achar algo posta aqui pra gente conhecer.