# Obter dados de imagem

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Meu sistema deve processar algumas imagens e obter dados chaves em texto. É claro, as imagens seguirão um padrão de estilo.

Por onde posso começar? Existe alguma API que possa me ajudar?

Comment: Você quer ler texto de imagens, é isso?

Comment: Exatamente. É isso mesmo.

Comment: Além da resposta que você já tem, você também pode obter ajuda em outras perguntas sobre o assunto aqui no SOPT. Basta procurar por [OCR (Optical Character Recognition)](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=OCR) ou [Tesseract](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=Tesseract).

Comment: Ah, o vídeo incluido [nessa resposta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/30847/73) parece ser bastante útil.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O motor mais comum e gratuito de OCR (reconhecimento de caracteres) que eu conheço é o Tesseract. Há dois aportes dele para .NET:

- https://code.google.com/p/tesseractdotnet/
- https://github.com/charlesw/tesseract

Recomendo passar as imagens para preto-e-branco antes de usar o Tesseract para ler. Preferencialmente, procure posicionar os textos na horizontal, e não passe textos muito pequenos, que ele pode se perder.

Outra dica é a [de configurar uma lista de caracteres permitidos para leitura](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/tesseract-ocr/0msQtTB_XrI). Dependendo de como está o texto, ele pode trocar alguns caracteres por outros.